# read.table automatic column names

Tags: r, dataframe

I noticed that when reading a large csv file via

```
output <- read.table( ..., header = TRUE, sep = ",")
```

The data frame which was created had some blank columns. These columns followed the naming pattern

```
 colnames(output)
     "Factor.1"   "Factor.2"   "etc"        "Stuff"      "X"          "X.1"        "X.2"        "X.3"        "X.4"        "X.5"       
     "X.6"        "X.7"        "X.8"        "X.9"        "X.10"       "X.11"       "X.12"       "X.13"      
     "X.14"       "X.15"       "X.16"       "X.17"       "X.18"       "X.19"       "X.20"       "X.21"      
     "X.22"       "X.23"       "X.24"       "X.25"       "X.26"       "X.27"       "X.28"       "X.29"      
     "X.30"       "X.31"       "X.32"       "X.33"
```

I noticed that in `?read.table` it states

> **col.names:**     a vector of optional names for the variables. The default
>   is to use "**V**" followed by the column number.

Why is it using X for me instead of V?

Edit:
This is what the csv file looks like

```
Date,Duration,Count,Factor 1,Factor 2,Factor 3,Hour,Day,Month,Year,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
1/1/2012 0:00,9.99,10,GC,LS,FT,0,7,1,2012,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
1/1/2012 1:00,9.63125,8,GC,LS,FT,1,7,1,2012,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
1/1/2012 2:00,7.388888889,3,GC,LS,FT,2,7,1,2012,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
1/1/2012 3:00,7.087037037,9,GC,LS,FT,3,7,1,2012,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
```

...

Comment: You can use `fread` if you are using a large csv file. Show your sample data.

Comment: @richard no I didn't get any warnings, This data frame is dynamic - but occasionally the software which spits out this data for me puts in these extra commas.

Comment: @Metrics, I didn't think sample data would have been needed to solve this problem, but i've added the first few lines anyway. :)

Comment: I think you are not right on this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's the relevant code snippet from `read.table()`

```
if (header) {
    .External(C_readtablehead, file, 1L, comment.char, 
              blank.lines.skip, quote, sep, skipNul)
    if (missing(col.names)) 
        col.names <- first
    else if (length(first) != length(col.names)) 
        warning("header and 'col.names' are of different lengths")
}
```

It's `if (missing(col.names)) col.names <- first` that's important. From there, we can go back and get `first`, defined for this situation as

```
first <- scan(textConnection(file), what = "", sep = ",", 
    nlines = 1, quiet = TRUE, skip = 0, strip.white = TRUE)
```

which results in

```
#  [1] "Date"     "Duration" "Count"    "Factor 1" "Factor 2" "Factor 3" "Hour"     "Day"      "Month"   
# [10] "Year"     ""         ""         ""         ""         ""         ""         ""         ""        
# [19] ""         ""         ""         ""         ""         ""         ""         ""         ""        
# [28] ""         ""         ""         ""         ""         ""         ""         ""         ""        
# [37] ""         ""         ""         ""         ""         ""         ""         ""
```

Then later on, `make.names()` is called on `col.names`, resulting in your names

```
make.names(first, unique = TRUE)
#  [1] "Date"     "Duration" "Count"    "Factor.1" "Factor.2" "Factor.3" "Hour"     "Day"      "Month"   
# [10] "Year"     "X"        "X.1"      "X.2"      "X.3"      "X.4"      "X.5"      "X.6"      "X.7"     
# [19] "X.8"      "X.9"      "X.10"     "X.11"     "X.12"     "X.13"     "X.14"     "X.15"     "X.16"    
# [28] "X.17"     "X.18"     "X.19"     "X.20"     "X.21"     "X.22"     "X.23"     "X.24"     "X.25"    
# [37] "X.26"     "X.27"     "X.28"     "X.29"     "X.30"     "X.31"     "X.32"     "X.33"
```

The reason why we got `X` and not `V` as noted in the docs is because the next condition after `if(header)` is

```
else if (missing(col.names)) 
    col.names <- paste0("V", 1L:cols)
```

But we never made it to that statement, and `make.names()` concatenates to `X` by default. There's a bit more to it than just this explanation. The best thing to do would be to go though the `read.table` source (it's complicated).

**Data:**

```
file <- "Date,Duration,Count,Factor 1,Factor 2,Factor 3,Hour,Day,Month,Year,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
1/1/2012 0:00,9.99,10,GC,LS,FT,0,7,1,2012,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
1/1/2012 1:00,9.63125,8,GC,LS,FT,1,7,1,2012,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
1/1/2012 2:00,7.388888889,3,GC,LS,FT,2,7,1,2012,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
1/1/2012 3:00,7.087037037,9,GC,LS,FT,3,7,1,2012,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,"
```

Comment: Ah ha! so it's the make.names function which puts an X on to it! Thanks mate! Thats interested as that the documentation tells us it's a 'V' then...

Comment: And `make.names("")` gives "X" - thanks Richard, it was bugging me too!

Comment: That happened because `else if (missing(col.names))  col.names <- paste0("V", 1L:cols)` comes after the `if(header)` statement, so we never made it to that statement

Comment: Very well done, thank you heaps! - in response to your side note, I did use to use `read.csv` - but I saw a few posts here on SO while I was learning R being very anti `read.csv` for some reason or other